# iOS 6 app hangs at splashscreen JQTouch + Phonegap

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, jqtouch

I have a weird problem with an App i'm developing with `jQTouch and Phonegap`. The App works fine most of the time, but sometimes (seems random) the App is stuck at the SplashScreen. Sometimes it still opens after a few minutes. It does nothing more than just load the `HTML, CSS` and `JS` files (no `Ajax` request or whatever). Is anyone familiar with this problem, or any ideas how to debug it?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Me too. I think we need to upgrade phonegap for our app.